# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 404: "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm working on a ChatGPT-App using React and Axios for making API requests to OpenAI's GPT-3.5 API. However, I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to make a request. I'm hoping someone can help me identify the issue and guide me on how to fix it. Here's the App.js and index.js code and error message:

##### Frontend

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const sendMessage = async () => {
    if (input.trim() === "") return;
  
    const userInput = input; // Store user input in a temporary variable
    setMessages([...messages, { type: "user", text: userInput }]);
    setInput("");
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/chat", { text: userInput });
      const gptResponse = response.data.message;
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [
        ...prevMessages,
        { type: "chatgpt", text: gptResponse },
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };
```

##### Backend

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const openai_api_key = "MYOPENAI-APIKEY";
const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": `Bearer ${openai_api_key}`,
};

app.post("/api/chat", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const input = req.body.text;
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions",
      {
        prompt: `User: ${input}\nChatGPT: `,
        max_tokens: 150,
        temperature: 0.7,
        n: 1,
      },
      { headers }
    );

    const gptResponse = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
    res.json({ message: gptResponse });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred while processing your request." });
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Error message:
`AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404`

I've verified that the API key is correct and the URL should be as well. Can anyone point me in the right direction for what's causing this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are three main differences between the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) and the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3 API).

#### If you're using OpenAI library ([NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai) or [Python](https://pypi.org/project/openai/))

*Note: OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. The code below differs depending on the version you currently have. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).*

The differences are the following:

1. Function

   - Completions API:

     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`: `openai.createCompletion`
     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`: `openai.completions.create`
   - Chat Completions API:

     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`: `openai.createChatCompletion`
     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`: `openai.chat.completions.create`
2. The `prompt` parameter (Completions API) is replaced by the `messages` parameter (Chat Completions API)
3. Response access

   - Completions API:

     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`: `return response.data.choices[0].text;`
     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`: `return response.choices[0].text;`
   - Chat Completions API:

     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`: `return response.data.choices[0].message.content;`
     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`: `return response.choices[0].message.content;`

##### Working example (NodeJS)

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function getChatGptResponse(request) {
  try {
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello!' }],
    });

    console.log(response.data.choices[0].message.content);
    return response.data.choices[0].message.content;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    return err;
  }
}

getChatGptResponse();
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
});

async function getChatGptResponse(request) {
  try {
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello!' }],
    });

    console.log(response.choices[0].message.content);
    return response.choices[0].message.content;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    return err;
  }
}

getChatGptResponse();
```

#### If you're not using OpenAI library

The differences are the following:

1. API endpoint

   - Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`
   - Chat Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`
2. The `prompt` parameter (Completions API) is replaced by the `messages` parameter (Chat Completions API)
3. Response access

   - Completions API:

     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:
        `const chatGptResponse = response.data.choices[0].text;`
     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:
        `const chatGptResponse = response.choices[0].text;`
   - Chat Completions API:

     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:
        `const chatGptResponse = response.data.choices[0].message.content;`
     - OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:
        `const chatGptResponse = response.choices[0].message.content;`

##### Working example

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const openaiApiKey = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${openaiApiKey}`,
};

app.post('/api/chat', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const input = req.body.text;

    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
      {
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages: [{role: 'user', content: `${input}`}],
      },
      { headers }
    );

    const chatGptResponse = response.data.choices[0].message.content;

    console.log(chatGptResponse);
    res.status(200).json({ message: chatGptResponse });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while processing your request' });
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const openaiApiKey = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${openaiApiKey}`,
};

app.post('/api/chat', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const input = req.body.text;

    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
      {
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages: [{role: 'user', content: `${input}`}],
      },
      { headers }
    );

    const chatGptResponse = response.choices[0].message.content;

    console.log(chatGptResponse);
    res.status(200).json({ message: chatGptResponse });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while processing your request' });
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```